# "investigate" or "investigating"

Tags: phrasal-verbs, infinitive-vs-gerund

> "This research was devoted to investigating the performance"

I always use Investigate after "to" as a infinitive, however I have seen some text that used "investigating" instead of "investigate", could you please help me which one is correct? investigate or investigating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, "This research was devoted **to** investigating the performance," that "to" is not part of an infinitive. It's a preposition associated with "devoted". "Devoted to" is an expression meaning "dedicated to",  "used for", "occupied with", or "spent on".

The infinitive form of "investigate" is "to investigate", just like other verbs. In your example, the word "investigating" is a gerund and performs a noun function within the sentence. In this case it is the object of the preposition "to".

Comment: If I substitute "devoted" with another verb such as "conducted", I have to use "investigating" in the same way? or "investigate? Could you please explain more, I couldn't underestimate clearly? thanks for taking your time.

Comment: I don't think "conducted" is a synonym of "devoted", so if you used "conducted", your sentence would have a different meaning. And it's hard to say what form of "investigate" you would use without specifying the whole rest of the sentence, prepositions and all. For instance, you could say, "This research was conducted **for the purpose of** investigating ..." *or* "This research was conducted **in order** to investigate ..." The appropriate form of "investigate" depends on the requirements of the other parts of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

There are some subtle differences between the two sentences

> This research is devoted to investigating.
>
> I wanted to investigate.

These differences are caused by the verb that is used.

The verb "devoted" is a part of a [verb-preposition combination](https://7esl.com/verb-preposition-combinations/) with the preposition "to". In the first sentence, "investigating" is a gerund noun that is used as the object of the preposition. For example, this sentence has the same structure:

> The statue is devoted to a historical figure.

In the second sentence, "to investigate" forms an infinitive that is the direct object of the verb "wanted".